# Enrollment upon arrival for U.S. Global Entry program for a U.S.-Canada flight

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, global-entry

I have been conditionally approved for the U.S. CBP's Global Entry program.  From what I understand, there is an enrollment through which you can do your interview upon arriving back in the U.S. from an international flight.  This program also appears to be available at the major Canadian airports.

I'm planning on flying roundtrip from SFO (San Francisco) to YVR (Vancouver).  Will it be possible for me to enroll upon arrival?  From what I understand, flights between the U.S. and Canada usually depart from/arrive at the domestic terminals in the U.S.

Would I enroll upon arriving in YVR?  Would I enroll as I go through customs exiting Canada at YVR?  Or would I enroll when I land back in SFO? Or is it just not possible to do enrollment upon arrival for U.S.-Canada flights?

Comment: Or you could just book a regular appointment at the Global Entry office at SFO. Much simpler.

Comment: That would require a separate trip to the airport.  It is out of the way and inconvenient.  Enrollment on arrival is simpler since I would have to pass through the checkpoint regardless.

Comment: @nukeguy did enrolling from YVR end up working out for you? I've been looking all over the place trying to get an answer to the exact same question.

Comment: @ChrisPhillips I ended up just doing it by a regular appointment in SFO, so I didn't get to try unfortunately.  Would love to hear if it works for you though.  Zach's answer below seems to indicate that you can enroll at YVR.

Comment: @nukeguy Yeah, I had already found the same information that Zach pointed to; was just hoping for additional confirmation. I'll be trying in a couple weeks and will try to remember to post back here :)

Comment: Just happened to realize that I forgot to write back here -- the answer below is absolutely correct. When you get to the US Customs line at Vancouver airport, just let the agent know that you're there for Enrollment on Arrival. They may send you to a different line entirely, or may have you go through the normal line and let the agent at the end know. They'll then set you aside for the interviews -- took us about 30 min to get through. (But it was not very busy at the time.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Enrollment on Arrival](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/enrollment-arrival) happens at US immigration when you're entering the US. As such, you would not do it when you arrive into Vancouver (you'll be entering Canada and will not see US officials) or when you land back in SFO (you'll arrive as a domestic flight since you already went through US immigration preclearance in Canada).

[Vancouver is listed as a participating Enrollment on Arrival airport](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/enrollment-arrival/locations/), so you can complete your enrollment there, when you go through US immigration to board your return flight back to the US.

According to that page, it is found at US immigration booths 21 and 23 at Vancouver and open from 6am to 6pm.